# How do I specify template parameters when running AWS SAM Local?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam-cli

Using [AWS SAM Local](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local) I can test my serverless application locally, which is awesome.

I can also [deploy to AWS](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local#package-and-deploy-to-lambda), which apparently takes the same flags as `aws cloudformation deploy`, so I can pass a parameters file with e.g. application secrets (API keys and such).

However, I can't find anything in `aws local start-api --help` or in the docs on Github about how to use a parameter file when testing locally.

How do I point to a parameters file to use with my template when running `sam local start-api`?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible on some versions of the SAM CLI. I've tried the above answer, but it doesn't seem to work with my version of the SAM CLI. I get `Error: no such option: --parameter-values`. `sam --version` yields 4.0. It also doesn't appear to be listed in the options for `sam local start-api --help` (`sam local start-api --help | grep -i parameter-values` yields nothing).

Comment: I cant believe there isn't an option already to pass the name of a cloud formation parameter file to the cloud formation stage of the sam deploy.  This would be so useful.

Comment: The feature request for `sam deploy` has been open for a few years - https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2054 - if it ever gets done it will be here. Also contains some other workarounds people are using.

Answer (score 44):

You can use the `--parameter-overrides` switch. The syntax is quite long winded, as below:

```
sam local start-api --parameter-overrides ParameterKey=Key1,ParameterValue=value1 ParameterKey=Key2,ParameterValue=value2
```

That is, you need to specify the **key** and **value** of each pair with **comma** separation.

And then each **pair** is separated with a **space**.

---

From `sam local start-api --help`:

```
  --parameter-overrides       Optional. A string that contains
                              CloudFormation parameter overrides encoded
                              as key=value pairs. Use the same format as
                              the AWS CLI, e.g. 'ParameterKey=KeyPairName,
                              ParameterValue=MyKey ParameterKey=InstanceTy
                              pe,ParameterValue=t1.micro'
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that in the help too. However, the question was specifically on how to pass a *file path* to a *file* with the parameter values, as you can do with `aws cloudformation deploy`, but I can't find how, or if, you can with `sam local start-api`.

Comment: Doesn't look like that one is supported. You can try using the shell for that with `--parameter-values $(cat myparams.cfg)`. The file will need to have a different format than usual, but it should work.

Comment: `sam local start-api --help` now also correctly states `--parameter-overrides`

Comment: is it possible to use `--parameter-override` from a file? I would like to keep my env parameters separate from my script

Comment: @Madeo it sounds like you might use a script for something like this. User input from the command line to select a number of options, which then runs the build/package/deploy sequence after the user has input their options.

Comment: How to refer to some deeply nested parameter in this option? E.g. Function -> Event -> Properties -> Path

Answer (score 6):

You can use the --parameter-overrides in sam deploy just like in aws cloudformation deploy with a small change:

Before:

```
sam deploy --template-file packaged.yaml --stack-name example-lambda --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --parameter-overrides ParameterKey=SourceS3Bucket ParameterValue=test-data-111
```

After:

```
sam deploy --template-file packaged.yaml --stack-name example-lambda --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --parameter-overrides SourceS3Bucket=test-data-111
```

Noticeable change:
ParameterKey, ParameterValue does not need to be explicitly specified in sam deploy. Helps me in local testing.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: is it possible to use `--parameters-overrides` as a .json file?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you can also use the `-n` or `--env-vars` parameter to pass environment variables in a JSON file to your functions. See the docs: [Test Your Serverless Applications Locally Using SAM CLI (Public Beta)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/test-sam-cli.html)

In short, your JSON file would look like (example copied from documentation):

```
{
  "MyFunction1": {
    "TABLE_NAME": "localtable",
    "BUCKET_NAME": "testBucket"
  },
  "MyFunction2": {
    "TABLE_NAME": "localtable",
    "STAGE": "dev"
  },
}
```

And then you can do:

```
 $ sam local start-api --env-vars env.json
```

This is specifically for environment variables for your lambda functions though, so it may not be entirely what you're after?

Comment: No; while useful, this doesn't solve the problem. For example, I can't use this approach to parametrize the name of a dynamodb table or things like that.

Answer (score 1):

My strange experience was that it depends on an order of the parameters. I had two parameters - SecretKey and DatabaseUri pointing to a Mongo instance. When I had the DatabaseUri first, the SecretKey was not loaded and the build failed upon a missing parameter SecretKey. When I was really desperate I swapped the parameters having the SecretKey first and it started to work!