# AWS SAM local and environment parameters

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I want to get rid off hardcoded passwords in my lambda that is deployed to AWS. I found I shall modify `packaged.yaml`:

```
Parameters:
  DATABASE_URI:
    Description: 'Required. MongoDB connection URL'
    Type: 'String'
Resources:
  BUDAuthorizeUserHandler:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: BUDAuthorizeUserHandler
      Handler: src/handlers/users/authorizeUser.handler
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Environment:
        Variables:
          MONGODB_URI: !Ref DATABASE_URI
```

This is the usage:

```
const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
console.log(MONGODB_URI);
```

So far so good and according to the specification. But I spent two hours trying to make it work locally.

Configuration file `env.json`

```
{
  "BUDAuthorizeUserHandler": {
     "MONGODB_URI": "mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/bud?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
   }
}
```

I tried these options but the environment variable was never defined:

```
sam local start-api --env-vars env.json

sam local start-api --parameter-overrides ParameterKey=DATABASE_URI,ParameterValue="mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/bud?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

I have walked through these pages:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1163
[aws-sam-local environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104665/aws-sam-local-environment-variables)
[How do I specify template parameters when running AWS SAM Local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266568/how-do-i-specify-template-parameters-when-running-aws-sam-local)
[Setting environmental variables with !Ref in AWS SAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697215/setting-environmental-variables-with-ref-in-aws-sam)

SAM CLI, version 0.39.0

How to make it work? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem in your case might be that the Parameter name `DATABASE_URI`  contains non-alphanumeric characters (underscore in your example). Try renaming it to `DatabaseUri` and doing the same in your `sam invoke local` command. It should work.

Also, you need the changes in `template.yaml`, not `packaged.yaml`. packaged.yaml is auto-generated when you run the `sam package` command.

On making these changes, following template.yaml works for me.

```
Parameters:
    DatabaseUri: # Changed this to remove underscore
        Description: 'Required. MongoDB connection URL'
        Type: 'String'
Resources:
    BUDAuthorizeUserHandler:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            FunctionName: BUDAuthorizeUserHandler
            Handler: index.pingWithEnvVariable # Ignore this change, my test function is at this location
            Runtime: nodejs10.x
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    MONGODB_URI: !Ref DatabaseUri # Removed underscore from here as well, obviously
```

index.js (returning the value of env variable in the output for testing)

```
exports.pingWithEnvVariable = async event => {
    const response = {};
    response.statusCode = 200;
    const env = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
    response.body = JSON.stringify({ env });
    return response;
};
```

used the same env.json as yours

```
$ sam local invoke BUDAuthorizeUserHandler  --env-vars env.json
START RequestId: 6a9d398c-fecd-1b07-c9a0-d9fe4293cfe1 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 6a9d398c-fecd-1b07-c9a0-d9fe4293cfe1
REPORT RequestId: 6a9d398c-fecd-1b07-c9a0-d9fe4293cfe1  Init Duration: 211.76 ms        Duration: 5.66 ms       Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 43 MB

{"statusCode":200,"body":"{\"env\":\"mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/bud?retryWrites=true\u0026w=majority\"}"}
```

Works with parameter overrides as well

```
$ sam local invoke BUDAuthorizeUserHandler  --parameter-overrides 'ParameterKey=DatabaseUri,ParameterValue=mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/bud?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
START RequestId: e0415251-2655-139b-e5df-5f9db658ca01 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: e0415251-2655-139b-e5df-5f9db658ca01
REPORT RequestId: e0415251-2655-139b-e5df-5f9db658ca01  Init Duration: 163.06 ms        Duration: 6.88 ms       Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 43 MB

{"statusCode":200,"body":"{\"env\":\"mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/bud?retryWrites=true\u0026w=majority\"}"}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try. Btw is it safe to store template.yaml in public git? I think there is no sensitive information but I worry, because I read an article about accidental commit of sensitive information that some cracker used to start lots of EC2 instances ..

Comment: As long as there are no credentials stored in template.yaml, I think there are no risks.

Comment: Updated my answer by editing your example. Both env-vars and parameter-overrides work for me after making minor changes to your template.yaml

Comment: Great stuff. MONGODB_URI is used from env.json, not DatabaseUri. I will accept your solution now, thank you. Can you upvote my question please?

Comment: sam package and deploy do not accept the --env-vars. How can I pass the parameters to AWS?
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Parameters: [DatabaseUri] must have values

Comment: Parameter override seems to work, but passing all data in command line is ugly. I would prefer json file.

Comment: Just adding the env vars under ```Resources``` in ```template.yaml``` works for me even with underscores.

Answer (score 1):

> samconfig.toml

```
[prod.deploy.parameters]
region = "us-east-1"
parameter_overrides = "TableName=\"banana-one\" DatabaseUri=\"https://prod.database.com\""
```

> template.yaml

```
Parameters:
  TableName:
    Type: String
  DatabaseUri:
    Type: String

Resources:
  BUDAuthorizeUserHandler:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
        FunctionName: BUDAuthorizeUserHandler
        Handler: index.pingWithEnvVariable
        Runtime: nodejs10.x
        Environment:
            Variables:
                MONGODB_URI: !Ref DatabaseUri
```

> Lambda File

```
const tableName = process.env.TableName;
```

> Command Line

```
sam deploy --guided --config-env prod
```

NOTE: Just add more to .toml file for other env's